# What standalone JavaScript compressing tools are there?

Tags: javascript, minify, jscompress

Currently I am using the site at http://javascriptcompressor.com/ to compress my JavaScript.
Is there any other standalone JavaScript compressing tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following are standalone:

- [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/download/#packer)

Comment: Oh and it might be worth mentioning that there are online YUI Compressors. Here's one that lets you upload multiple files and compress them into one: http://yui.2clics.net/

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.cortex-creations.com/phpjso/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/jscompress.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using YUI Compressor and it works fine for me. No problem with compressing and it does not produces errors in the output code, which was the problem with other compressing software. It's easy to use and you can start with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://openwaf-js-mini.appspot.com/ as good as YUI JS Compressor...